# Vuetify DataTable sortable and filter not work after read data from api laravel

Tags: vue.js, datatable, axios, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify DataTable sortable and filter not work after read data from api laravel

Sorting and filtering does not work when I read data from Laravel API.

Works for static data.

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="posts"
        class="elevation-1"
      ></v-data-table>


data () {
    return {
      headers: [
 
        { text: 'id', value: 'id' },
        { text: 'title', value: 'title' },
      ],
      posts: []
})
```

Comment: readfromapi (){  this.$axios.post(.then(response){  this.post = response.data.result })}

Comment: https://codepen.io/morphatic/pen/qBOrWGE  in this example sortable not work. but my code not work sortable and filter

Comment: Can you update the question to show the actual API data in the response?